# Maven Parallel Build in a Multi-module Project

Tags: java, spring

I have a multi-module project that has a parent and its child modules. I am trying to build all of them in parallel - My question is does Maven spawn a new JVM instance of each child module? Each child module is a Spring Boot application (I know that each Java application needs its own JVM instance, is it the case here as well?)

I ma asking this question as I want to share a bean across these children. But in case they are running in separate JVM instances, there would be no way to share.

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean. You use maven to **build** or **run** the applications ? Sharing a bean at build time does not look like something one should want to do, so I'm guessing you are talking about **running** the apps, but maven has little to do in this case (you may use maven on your development environment, but usually it's not the case in production ?). And, generally speaking, different spring boot apps are meant to be each in its own JVM (or you have to customize the hell out of everything, e.g. the `application.properties` file).

Comment: I use Maven to build the application - which includes the test (hence the application contexts come into picture). I want to share a bean across two applications during runtime.

Comment: I would advise not trying to do that. So many things can go wrong. As an example, even if "sharing a bean" is possible, how can you know 1/ that all your modules test are running at a given point in time (maybe only one is, and the rest are going to launch in a few minutes) : what does sharing mean then ?. 2/ what if the application contexts are different in each module (e.g. mocking of the bean in one test, not in the other) ? 3/ What happens if your bean is statefull and the order of execution is not predictible ? 4/ what happens in 6 months, when somebody else has to figure this all out ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, maven can do parallel build as long as it is multi-core device . Because maven use multiple threads to run the things in parallel. 
Maven 3.x has that options to do parallel builds.

```
mvn -T 4 clean install # Builds with 4 threads
```

For more details refer [MavenBuilds](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3)

And since they are running in same JVM, you can share your bean instance. And hopefully it should be under Singleton Scope and make sure the corresponding module which has this bean instantiation should be run first or trigger first.

Comment: So it does not start a new JVM for each child?

Comment: No, it is 1 JVM with multiple threads. This also explains the -T argument:

-T,--threads <arg>                     Thread count, for instance 2.0C
                                       where C is core multiplied