# How to Build Maven Modules in Parallel in Separate JVMs

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin, maven-reactor

We have a multi-module Maven project that takes about 2 hours to build and we would like to speed that up by making use of concurrency.

We are aware of the `-T` option which (as explained i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57457215/14443306)) allows using multiple threads within the same JVM for the build.

Sadly, there is a lot of legacy code (which uses a lot of global states) in the project which makes executing multiple test in parallel in a single JVM very hard. Removing all of these blockers from the project would be a lot of work which we would like to avoid.

The surefire and failsafe plugins have multiple options regarding parallel execution behavior, however, as I understand it, this would only parallelize the test executions. Also, spawning a separate JVM for each test (class) seems kind of overkill to me. That would probably just as soon cause the build to take even longer than it does now.

Ideally, we would like to do the parallelization on the Maven reactor level and have it build each module in its own (single threaded) JVM with up to x JVMs running in parallel.

So my question is: is there a way to make maven create a separate JVM for each module build?
Alternatively, can we parallelize the build while making sure that tests (over all modules) are executed sequentially?

Comment: Why even have it as a single multi-module project then? If you have different projects, then you'll only need to rebuild them when something changes.

Comment: One reason is that we actually want to be able to easily build all dependent modules of the changed module.  
We had separate modules before and wanted to avoid breaking things farther downstream when changing something in a core module.

Comment: There is not way to have a separate JVM for each module... The problem seemed to be located within the tests so use the options for surefire/failsafe plugin ..and let Maven build the reactor in parallel ... as mentioned via `-T`... and the real problem is located in the global states of your tests or production code... the forked JVM for the tests can be resued and not fully restarted... etc. the other question is: About what number of modules do we talk about? Which Maven version/JDK version etc. do you use?

Comment: We have ~50 modules using Java 17 with Maven 3.8

Comment: 50 modules is not much... taking 2 hours sounds crazy long... how long does the plain build take and how long does it take with unit tests and how long does it take with only running integration tests... ?

Comment: Ok. So it seems Surefire and Failsafe already fork JVMs for the tests by default. So the default behavior has one single shared JVM for all Builds but separate JVMs for unit/integration tests of each module. Which is not exactly what I asked for in the original question but solves all of my issues. Still thanks for everyones' help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure this works but I guess if you use Maven Toolchains, then each module will start its own forked JVM for the tests, not reusing already running ones.

I guess it is worth a try.

Comment: That's an interesting idea! Do you think the JVMs won't be reused even if the configured toolchain is the same for each module? I'll definitely try that! Thanks!